# 2 webbrowser in HtmlElement command

Tags: html, vb.net

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1 And WebBrowser2.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In elements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("id") = "skip_ad_button" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")


        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I want to put 2 webbrowser in the same timer3![enter image description here][1]

Picture: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVnG2.jpg][1]

Comment: Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1 And WebBrowser2.Document.All

Answer (score 1):

If you make an array of `HtmlElementCollection` you can control more than one document at the same time using this code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection() = New HtmlElementCollection() {WebBrowser1.Document.All, WebBrowser2.Document.All}

    For Each webpageelementcollection As HtmlElementCollection In elements
        For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In webpageelementcollection
            If webpageelement.GetAttribute("id") = "ELEMENT_ID" Then
                webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```